# Input field error when using decimal numbers on apple touch devices

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am encountering a problem when using input field on apple touch devices. When i write a number and add a decimal dot (.) after it, the number is replaced with 0 immediately, but if i add a decimal dot after 0, then it works. It only happens on apple touch devices, on other devices it's working fine. Any ideas how to solve this?

```
<input
      v-if="!advancedAttributeUsed"
      ref="input"
      step="any"
      :value="internalAttribute.value"
      :type="type"
      :disabled="disabled"
      :data-test-id="dataTestId"
      :data-cy="dataCy"
      class="custom-text-field"
      @input="handleInput"
      @blur="handleBlur"
      @focus="handleFocus"
      @keyup.enter="
        () => {
          $refs.input.blur();
          $emit('unfocus');
        }
      "
    />

handleInput(event) {
      let value = event.target.value;
      value = value.replace(/,/g, ".");
      if (!isNaN(value)) {
        this.internalAttribute.value = Number(value);
        console.log("handleInput", this.internalAttribute);
        this.$emit("input", this.internalAttribute);
      }
    },
```